# Get Emails through ASPOSE for Office365 Users with MFA enabled

Tags: office365, imap, aspose.email

I'm building an application getting emails for Office365 users using ASPOSE.

My users have MFA enabled so I can't use [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc#:%7E:text=If%20users%20need%20to%20use%20multi%2Dfactor%20authentication%20(MFA)%20to%20log%20in%20to%20the%20application%2C%20they%20will%20be%20blocked%20instead.) like recommanded in [Aspose documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc#:%7E:text=If%20users%20need%20to%20use%20multi%2Dfactor%20authentication%20(MFA)%20to%20log%20in%20to%20the%20application%2C%20they%20will%20be%20blocked%20instead.)

Once I get my access token, I need it to refresh when it expires.

I searched for hours in Microsoft and Aspose documentation and I'm a bit lost.

Does someone went through the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: Usually you would use microsoft’s MSAL or ADAL libraries to do manage microsoft oauth tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following sections of Microsoft documentation:

- [Acquiring tokens silently (from the cache)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-acquire-cache-tokens#acquiring-tokens-silently-from-the-cache)
- [Get a token from the token cache using MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/acquire-token-silently)
- [Best practices for MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/getting-started/best-practices)

> MSAL maintains a token cache (or two caches for confidential client
> applications) and caches a token after it's been acquired. In many
> cases, attempting to silently get a token will acquire another token
> with more scopes based on a token in the cache. It's also capable of
> refreshing a token when it's getting close to expiration (as the token
> cache also contains a refresh token).

Thus, you should monitor the access token expiration or force a refresh after a certain time interval (e.g. 30 min):

```cs
AuthenticationResult result;
try
{
 // will handle expired Access Tokens by fetching new ones using the Refresh Token
 result = await AcquireTokenSilent(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
}
catch(MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
 result = AcquireTokenXXXX(scopes, ..).WithXXX(…).ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Also, you can refer to the [blog article](https://blog.aspose.com/email/connect-to-microsoft365-mailbox-using-modern-authentication-in-c-.net/) explaining how to use modern authentication with Aspose.Email to connect to Microsoft365.